# unable to resume activity NULL POINTER EXCEPTION & Error inflating class fragment?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, nullpointerexception, inflate-exception

hello guys i'm having a problem regarding map fragment, i have integrated google maps into a fragment that get called by drawer Main activity

the problem is that when ever i re-click on you which display map fragment the app crashes, in the fallowing code u'll find Main activity Home fragment which is map fragment, `xml` layout and `logcat` any help is really appreciated thanks in advance
`MainActivity`:

```
package info.androidhive.slidingmenu;

import info.androidhive.slidingmenu.adapter.NavDrawerListAdapter;
import info.androidhive.slidingmenu.model.NavDrawerItem;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.content.res.TypedArray;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.PopupMenu;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    private ListView mDrawerList;
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;
    private static int lastClicked = 0;
    public static int filterListFunc = 1;
    // nav drawer title
    private CharSequence mDrawerTitle;
    // static var to change filter functionality
    public static int filterFunc;
    // used to store app title
    private CharSequence mTitle;

    // slide menu items
    private String[] navMenuTitles;
    private TypedArray navMenuIcons;

    private ArrayList<NavDrawerItem> navDrawerItems;
    private NavDrawerListAdapter adapter;

    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mTitle = mDrawerTitle = getTitle();

        // load slide menu items
        navMenuTitles = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.nav_drawer_items);

        // nav drawer icons from resources
        navMenuIcons = getResources()
                .obtainTypedArray(R.array.nav_drawer_icons);

        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_slidermenu);

        navDrawerItems = new ArrayList<NavDrawerItem>();

        // adding nav drawer items to array
        // Home
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[0], navMenuIcons
                .getResourceId(0, -1)));
        // Find People
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[1], navMenuIcons
                .getResourceId(1, -1)));
        // Photos
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[2], navMenuIcons
                .getResourceId(2, -1)));
        // Communities, Will add a counter here
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[3], navMenuIcons
                .getResourceId(3, -1), true, "22"));
        // Pages
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[4], navMenuIcons
                .getResourceId(4, -1)));
        // What's hot, We will add a counter here
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[5], navMenuIcons
                .getResourceId(5, -1), true, "50+"));

        // Recycle the typed array
        navMenuIcons.recycle();

        mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new SlideMenuClickListener());

        // setting the nav drawer list adapter
        adapter = new NavDrawerListAdapter(getApplicationContext(),
                navDrawerItems);
        mDrawerList.setAdapter(adapter);

        // enabling action bar app icon and behaving it as toggle button
        getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

        mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout,
                R.drawable.ic_drawer, // nav menu toggle icon
                R.string.app_name, // nav drawer open - description for
                                    // accessibility
                R.string.app_name // nav drawer close - description for
                                    // accessibility
        ) {
            public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
                getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
                // calling onPrepareOptionsMenu() to show action bar icons
                invalidateOptionsMenu();
            }

            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                getActionBar().setTitle(mDrawerTitle);
                // calling onPrepareOptionsMenu() to hide action bar icons
                invalidateOptionsMenu();
            }
        };
        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            // on first time display view for first nav item
            displayView(0);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Slide menu item click listener
     * */
    private class SlideMenuClickListener implements
            ListView.OnItemClickListener {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                long id) {
            // display view for selected nav drawer item

            if (lastClicked == position) {
                lastClicked = position;
                mDrawerLayout.closeDrawers();

            }
            displayView(position);
        }

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // toggle nav drawer on selecting action bar app icon/title
        if (mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
            return true;
        }
        // Handle action bar actions click

        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.action_normal:

            HomeFragment.setMapType("normal");
            return true;

        case R.id.action_hyprid:
            HomeFragment.setMapType("hyprid");
            return true;
        case R.id.action_satellite:
            HomeFragment.setMapType("satellite");
            return true;
        case R.id.action_terrain:
            HomeFragment.setMapType("terrain");
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }

    /* *
     * Called when invalidateOptionsMenu() is triggered
     */
    @Override
    public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // if nav drawer is opened, hide the action items
        boolean drawerOpen = mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(mDrawerList);
        menu.findItem(R.id.action_normal).setVisible(!drawerOpen);
        return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    /**
     * Diplaying fragment view for selected nav drawer list item
     * */
    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    private void displayView(int position) {
        // update the main content by replacing fragments
        Fragment fragment = null;
        switch (position) {
        case 0:
            filterFunc = 1;

            fragment = new HomeFragment();
            mDrawerLayout.closeDrawers();
            break;
        case 1:

            PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(getApplicationContext(),
                    mDrawerList.getChildAt(1), Gravity.RIGHT + Gravity.RIGHT);
            // Inflating the Popup using xml file
            popup.getMenuInflater()
                    .inflate(R.menu.poupup_menu, popup.getMenu());

            // registering popup with OnMenuItemClickListener
            popup.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
                public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
                    if (filterFunc == 1) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                "You Clicked : " + item.getTitle(),
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        return true;
                    } else if (filterFunc == 2) {

                        if (item.getTitle().equals("Employees")) {

                            filterListFunc = 1;
                            Fragment fragment = new PhotosFragment();
                            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
                            fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                                    .replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment)
                                    .commit();
                            mDrawerLayout.closeDrawers();
                            return true;
                        } else if (item.getTitle().equals("Tickets")) {
                            filterListFunc = 2;
                            Fragment fragment = new PhotosFragment();
                            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
                            fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                                    .replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment)
                                    .commit();
                            mDrawerLayout.closeDrawers();
                            return true;
                        }

                    }

                    return false;
                }
            });

            popup.show();// showing popup menu
            mDrawerList.getChildAt(0).setClickable(false);
            break;
        case 2:
            filterFunc = 2;
            fragment = new PhotosFragment();
            mDrawerLayout.closeDrawers();
            break;
        case 3:
            filterFunc = 0;
            fragment = new CommunityFragment();
            mDrawerLayout.closeDrawers();
            break;
        case 4:
            filterFunc = 0;
            fragment = new PagesFragment();
            mDrawerLayout.closeDrawers();
            break;
        case 5:
            filterFunc = 0;
            fragment = new WhatsHotFragment();
            mDrawerLayout.closeDrawers();
            break;

        default:
            break;
        }

        if (fragment != null) {
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment).commit();

            // update selected item and title, then close the drawer

            mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
            mDrawerList.setSelection(position);
            setTitle(navMenuTitles[position]);
            mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
        } else {
            // error in creating fragment
            Log.e("MainActivity", "Error in creating fragment");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void setTitle(CharSequence title) {
        mTitle = title;
        getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
    }

    /**
     * When using the ActionBarDrawerToggle, you must call it during
     * onPostCreate() and onConfigurationChanged()...
     */

    @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Sync the toggle state after onRestoreInstanceState has occurred.
        mDrawerToggle.syncState();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        // Pass any configuration change to the drawer toggls
        mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }

}
```

MapFragment:

```
package info.androidhive.slidingmenu;

import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap.OnInfoWindowClickListener;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.BitmapDescriptorFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.CameraPosition;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.internal.f;

import android.app.Fragment;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Bitmap.Config;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.location.Criteria;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {
    // latitude and longitude of an employee just demonstration
    // static var get byte image changes into image adapter
    public static byte[] iconEmp;
    public static Bitmap bitmapfree;
    public static Bitmap bitmapBusy;
    public static byte[] bitMapData;
    public static byte[] bitMapData2;
    // Google Map
    static GoogleMap googleMap;

    public HomeFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container,
                false);
        // MainActivity e = new MainActivity();
        try {
            // Loading map
            initilizeMap();

            googleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);

        } catch (Exception ee) {
            ee.printStackTrace();
        }
        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        initilizeMap();

    }

    /**
     * function to load map If map is not created it will create it for you
     * */
    void initilizeMap() {

        googleMap = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(
                R.id.map)).getMap();

        // check if map is created successfully or not
        if (googleMap == null) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Sorry! unable to create maps",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        // ///----------------------------------Zooming camera to position
        // user-----------------

        LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getActivity()
                .getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        Criteria criteria = new Criteria();

        Location location = locationManager
                .getLastKnownLocation(locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria,
                        false));
        if (location != null) {
            googleMap
                    .animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(
                            new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location
                                    .getLongitude()), 13));

            CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder()
                    .target(new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location
                            .getLongitude())) // Sets the center of the map to
                                                // location user
                    .zoom(14) // Sets the zoom
                    .bearing(90) // Sets the orientation of the camera to east
                    .tilt(40) // Sets the tilt of the camera to 30 degrees
                    .build(); // Creates a CameraPosition from the builder
            googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory
                    .newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));

        }

        // -------------------Zooming camera to position
        // user-----------------
        googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

        googleMap.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(true);
        // def employee marker depending on a certain location

        // def tickets marker in a certain location
        Resources res = getResources();
        Drawable drawable = res.getDrawable(R.drawable.free);

        Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) drawable).getBitmap();

        ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, stream);

        bitMapData = stream.toByteArray();
        Drawable drawable2 = res.getDrawable(R.drawable.buzy);

        Bitmap bitmap2 = ((BitmapDrawable) drawable2).getBitmap();

        ByteArrayOutputStream stream2 = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bitmap2.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, stream2);

        bitMapData2 = stream2.toByteArray();
        // fill employee data
        Employee emp = new Employee("1", "noor ahmad", "Routine", "0796548755",
                "Free", 31.0000, 35.0000, "123");
        Employee emp1 = new Employee("2", "ahmad mohammed", "Repair",
                "0796556457", "NotFree", 31.9869, 35.8715, "123");
        Employee emp2 = new Employee("3", "thaer abdullah",
                "Preventive Maintenance", "0785461444", "NotFree", 31.9885,
                35.8481, "123");
        ArrayList<Employee> e = new ArrayList<Employee>();
        e.add(emp);
        e.add(emp1);
        e.add(emp2);
        // def ticket's images
        Drawable drawableFixed = res.getDrawable(R.drawable.fixed);
        Bitmap bitmapFixed = ((BitmapDrawable) drawableFixed).getBitmap();
        Drawable drawableunFixed = res.getDrawable(R.drawable.unfixed);
        Bitmap bitmapunFixed = ((BitmapDrawable) drawableunFixed).getBitmap();
        Drawable drawableUnderM = res.getDrawable(R.drawable.underm);
        Bitmap bitmapUnderM = ((BitmapDrawable) drawableUnderM).getBitmap();
        // fill tickets data
        Tickets tic = new Tickets(1, 1, 1, "Preventive_Maintenance", "",
                31.9935, 35.8532, "5/2/2015", "fixed");
        Tickets tic1 = new Tickets(2, 2, 2, "Repair", "not working", 31.9920,
                35.8540, "5/2/2015", "unfixed");
        Tickets tic2 = new Tickets(3, 3, 3, "Preventive_Maintenance", "",
                31.9923, 35.8459, "5/2/2015", "under maintainance");
        ArrayList<Tickets> t = new ArrayList<Tickets>();
        t.add(tic);
        t.add(tic1);
        t.add(tic2);
        // loop around employees and insert markers into the map
        for (Employee e1 : e) {
            MarkerOptions markerT = new MarkerOptions().position(
                    new LatLng(e1.getEmpLatitude(), e1.getEmpLongitude()))
                    .title(e1.getEmpName());

            // Changing marker icon

            bitmapfree = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bitMapData, 0,
                    bitMapData.length);
            bitmapBusy = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bitMapData2, 0,
                    bitMapData2.length);
            bitmapfree = eraseColor(bitmap, -16777216);
            bitmapBusy = eraseColor(bitmap2, -16777216);
            if (e1.getEmpWorkState().equals("NotFree")) {
                iconEmp = bitMapData2;
                markerT.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(bitmapBusy));
            } else if (e1.getEmpWorkState().equals("Free")) {
                iconEmp = bitMapData;
                markerT.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(bitmapfree));
            }
            // adding employee marker to the map
            googleMap.addMarker(markerT);
        }
        // loop around tickets and insert markers into the map
        for (Tickets t1 : t) {
            MarkerOptions markerT = new MarkerOptions()
                    .position(
                            new LatLng(t1.getTicketLatitude(), t1
                                    .getTicketlongitude())).title(
                            t1.getTicketCategory());
            // Changing marker icon

            if (t1.getTicketState().equals("fixed")) {

                markerT.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(bitmapFixed));
            } else if (t1.getTicketState().equals("unfixed")) {

                markerT.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(bitmapunFixed));
            } else if (t1.getTicketState().equals("under maintainance")) {
                markerT.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(bitmapUnderM));
            }
            // adding employee marker to the map
            googleMap.addMarker(markerT);
        }
        googleMap.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPause();
        Fragment fragment = (getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map));
        android.app.FragmentTransaction ft = getActivity().getFragmentManager()
                .beginTransaction();
        ft.remove(fragment);
        ft.commit();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroyView() {

        super.onDestroyView();

        Fragment fragment = (getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map));
        android.app.FragmentTransaction ft = getActivity().getFragmentManager()
                .beginTransaction();
        ft.remove(fragment);
        ft.commit();

    }

    public static void setMapType(String n) {
        if (n == "normal") {
            googleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
        } else if (n == "hyprid") {
            googleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID);
        } else if (n == "satellite") {
            googleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_SATELLITE);
        } else if (n == "terrain") {
            googleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_TERRAIN);
        }

    }

    // erase bitmap background black
    public static Bitmap eraseColor(Bitmap src, int color) {
        int width = src.getWidth();
        int height = src.getHeight();
        Bitmap b = src.copy(Config.ARGB_8888, true);
        b.setHasAlpha(true);

        int[] pixels = new int[width * height];
        src.getPixels(pixels, 0, width, 0, 0, width, height);

        for (int i = 0; i < width * height; i++) {
            if (pixels[i] == color) {
                pixels[i] = 0;
            }
        }
        b.setPixels(pixels, 0, width, 0, 0, width, height);
        return b;
    }

}
```

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

   <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>


</RelativeLayout>
```

LogCat:[image]

another error im getting : this occurs when i click on you twice 
[image]

Comment: Find out what had happened at `HomeFragment` line 94. Or tell me which line is the 94th.

Comment: 93-  LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager)                           94-           getActivity().getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
95-  Criteria criteria = new Criteria();

Comment: getActivity(), seems this method is returning null

Comment: any suggestions ? and why does it return null when its called twice i also get inflate exception i'll post it in asecond

Comment: Don't remove Fragment in your `onPause` method

Comment: Still there is a problem it gives an inflate exception when ever I press twice on the map fragment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have found the solution for those two problems so the first one: 
1-null pointer exception unable to resume activity it occurs when ever i change the phone orientation from landscape to portrait and the solution is to: remove -

```
@Override
public void onPause() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onPause();
    Fragment fragment = (getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map));
    android.app.FragmentTransaction ft = getActivity().getFragmentManager()
            .beginTransaction();
    ft.remove(fragment);
    ft.commit();
}

@Override
public void onDestroyView() {

    super.onDestroyView();

    Fragment fragment = (getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map));
    android.app.FragmentTransaction ft = getActivity().getFragmentManager()
            .beginTransaction();
    ft.remove(fragment);
    ft.commit();

}
```

from the Map Fragment
2-the second one was the error inflating class fragment which cause duplicates "calling the map fragment twice and loading it twice" and the solution that i've found is to create an if statement controls the loading process:

```
    if(HomeFragment.googleMap != null){
    LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager)getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    Criteria criteria = new Criteria();

    Location location = locationManager
            .getLastKnownLocation(locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria,
                    false));
    if (location != null) {
        HomeFragment.googleMap
                .animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(
                        new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location
                                .getLongitude()), 13));

        CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder()
                .target(new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location
                        .getLongitude())) // Sets the center of the map to
                                            // location user
                .zoom(14) // Sets the zoom
                .bearing(0) // Sets the orientation of the camera to east
                .tilt(40) // Sets the tilt of the camera to 30 degrees
                .build(); // Creates a CameraPosition from the builder
        HomeFragment.googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory
                .newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));

    }
}else{
            fragment = new HomeFragment();}
            mDrawerLayout.closeDrawers();
            break;
```

and on other cases i added

```
HomeFragment.googleMap = null;
```

if the case lead to another fragment and if it doesn't i just let it be.
hope this will help others.
thank you